# How to remove git push origin master error

Tags: git

I have working on git but i have get this type of error while push the data

```
root@test-pc:/opt/lampp/htdocs/itcrowdsource# git push origin master
Username for 'http://192.168.1.34:8080': test.test
Password for 'http://test.test@192.168.1.34:8080': ****
```

This type error show.

```
To http://192.168.1.34:8080/scm/git/projectsource
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.1.34:8080/scm/git/projectsource'
```

Comment: Please include on the question the full output of git push using `--verbose` flag

Comment: Github has a [page](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/) dedicated dealing with non-fast-forward errors.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: [Dealing with non-fast-forward errors](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/) <sub>(thanks @buratino)</sub>

---

This is a warning and it is preventing you from doing something destructive.

The `master` branch you have on **your** machine has diverged from what was on the **server** (`origin`).

You have three choices:

1. loose the changes on **your** computer with:

   ```
   git reset --hard origin/master
   ```
2. Ignore the changes on the server (See [**warnings**!!!!!](http://willi.am/blog/2014/08/12/the-dark-side-of-the-force-push/)):

   ```
   git push --force
   ```
3. Merge/rebase the two together and manually resolve all the conflicts:

   ```
   git merge origin/master
   git push
   ```

   or

   ```
   git rebase origin/master
   git push
   ```

Merge to make a merge commit; rebase to put your changes *on top of* the changes on the server.